# How to fix "cannot unmarshal !!str `image:j...` into config.RawService" error while running docker compose on ecs-cli?

Tags: docker-compose, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

I am setting up Containerized Deployment for my project as per this [AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-technical-content/latest/jenkins-on-aws/containerized-deployment.html). I have setup AWS CLI to follow the steps from the documentation. I have successfully build Jenkins and Jenkins Docker Volume image and pushed it to my repo on ECR. I installed ECS-CLI to run the docker compose file but I am getting *"yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 2: cannot unmarshal !!str image:j... into config.RawService"* error  on running the docker compose file.

This is my first time using docker compose and when I researched I found out it can be a version issue. The ECS-CLI now support all the three versions of docker compose, so it cannot be a version issue.

**Command:** ecs-cli compose service up

**docker-compose.yml** (jenkins is the jenkins-master image from the documentation):

```
jenkins:
  image:jenkins
  cpu_shares:100
  mem_limit:2000
  ports:"8080:8080","50000:50000" 
  volumes_from:jenkins_dv
jenkins_dv:
  image:jenkins_dv
  cpu_shares:100
  mem_limit:500
```

**Actual Result**

ERRO[0000] Could not parse config for project awsinfra : yaml: unmarshal errors:

line 2: cannot unmarshal !!str `image:j...` into config.RawService

line 8: cannot unmarshal !!str `image:j...` into config.RawService

ERRO[0000] Unable to open ECS Compose Project            error="yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 2: cannot unmarshal !!str `image:j...` into config.RawService\n  line 8: cannot unmarshal !!str `image:j...` into config.RawService"

FATA[0000] Unable to create and read ECS Compose Project  error="yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 2: cannot unmarshal !!str `image:j...` into config.RawService\n  line 8: cannot unmarshal !!str `image:j...` into config.RawService"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is valid YAML, but each key `jenkins` and `jenkins_dv` have as value a multi-line plain scalar string (plain as in: without quotes). And docker-compose doesn't know what to do with those strings, it expects a mapping (Python `dict`)

What you want to have as values are mappings and for that you need at least to use a value indicator between the key and the value. The value indicator in YAML is a colon (':'), followed by white-space (i.e. a newline as with the indicator following `jenkins`, or a space.

Try:

```
jenkins:
  image: jenkins
  cpu_shares: 100
  mem_limit: 2000
  ports: ["8080:8080", "50000:50000"]
  volumes_from: jenkins_dv
jenkins_dv:
  image: jenkins_dv
  cpu_shares: 100
  mem_limit: 500
```

IIRC the value for `ports` has to be a sequence, so I changed its value to a flow style sequence. The space after the entry seperator (`,`) in that sequence is not strictly necessary, but makes things IMHO more readable. You could also do:

```
  ports: 
  - "8080:8080"
  - "50000:50000"
```

Comment: It worked. What would be the best source to learn about docker-compoes file format?

Comment: For the actual docker-compose elements: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/. But this is more of a misunderstanding of the YAML file format, so either read up on that, or if you want to see what your YAML input looks like as JSON or Python use http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/. If you paste your compose file there, you'll see that the "mapping" gets read as a string.